# Графики в JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

Есть отличная библиотека для работы с графиками в Swing - jfree. В ней есть очень хороший класс - JFreeChart. С помощью него можно не только строить график, но и интерактивно взаимодействовать с ним. То есть, я строю график в реальном времени, в любой момент могу его остановить и что самое важное - с помощью правой кнопки мыши могу приближать график, сохранять его в PNG, масштабировать и многое другое.

Есть возможность перенести этот класс в JavaFX, т.к. в нем уже реализована поддержка. Пробовал - все ужасно тормозит, мне не нравится.

Есть ли в JavaFX подобный класс ? Пробовал LineChart - он не обладает и половиной той же функциональности.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть просто надо их правильно освоить и понять. 
Ниже ссылки:

Раз ссылка - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/charts.htm - офф документация

Два ссылака - https://habrahabr.ru/post/242009/ - Чуть чуть об этом на хабре

Три ссылка - https://rterp.wordpress.com/stockchartsfx/ - Это фреймворк разработанный на ФХ для работы с графиками

Приятного обучения

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.